# something is wrong when i run turtlesim_node

Tags: ros, turtlesim, rosrun, turtlesim-node

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am a beginner, I am learning ROS.org    I use the ‘indigo’ version
when i run this  "rosrun turtlesim turtlesim_node"
The screen display
[ERROR] [1505802741.783016851]: [registerPublisher] Failed to contact master at [localhost:11311]. retrying...
How to resolve this problem?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/271139/something-is-wrong-when-i-run-turtlesim_node/) by [summer](https://answers.ros.org/users/31948/summer/) on ROS Answers with karma: 15 on 2017-09-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Do you initialized the ros? with the roscore?

Try type the command " roscore " before. In another terminal's window

http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/CommandLineTools#roscore

---

Originally posted by [Teo Cardoso](https://answers.ros.org/users/31965/teo-cardoso/) with karma: 378 on 2017-09-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [summer](https://answers.ros.org/users/31948/summer/) on 2017-09-20**:
Ok ,it is working .Thank you very much.

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2017-09-21**:
@summer, if this answered your question then please click the checkmark to accept the answer.